# Referencing a string within an Index Formula Array in Excel VBA ROW(1:1)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, formula

Need some help referencing a string in an Index formula array

My code below:

```
Sub Loop_Test2()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim CountAll As Long
Dim CountXL As Long
Dim CustomerName As String

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate

CountAll = ActiveSheet.Range("A35")

For j = 1 To CountAll
i = 2

CountXL = Cells(i, j).Value
R = 1
For i = 1 To CountXL
CustomerName = Cells(1, j).Value
'MsgBox CustomerName
MsgBox R
Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=""" & CustomerName & """,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(R:R))*1,2),0)"
R = R + 1
Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

I am trying to put a reference in this part:

```
ROW(1:1)
```

change it to:

```
ROW(""" & R & """ : """ & R & """)
```

However receiving an object error 1004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete double quotes

```
ROW(" & R & " : " & R & ")
```

Full:

```
Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=""" & CustomerName & """,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(" & R & ":" & R & "))*1,2),0)"
```

***Example to understand:***

```
a = 10
b = "sometext_" & a & "_sometext"
```

?b in immediate window (Ctrl+G) will print:

> sometext_10_sometext

```
b = "sometext_""" & a & """_sometext"
```

will print:

> sometext_"10"_sometext

Double quotes in editor goes as quote in variable.